# Handling xml files with different structures and different names

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a method and I want different users to pass me xml files.  These files will have different names for the elements I am looking for and the elements I am looking for maybe at different structures.  My first impression was that we should just tell them to pass in the xml in a standard format.  However this is how they have their data and they insist that it is much easier if they don't have to convert it.

What can I do to take in data of all types?

Have them pass in a dictionary?
number = mydata/numbers

What is the easiest way for them to define their data to me without actually changing it?

sample1

```
<numbers>
15
</numbers>
```

sample2

```
<mydata>
<mynumbers>
15
</mynumbers>
</mydata>
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question if the data format is mandated by the users or not. What can you demand from them?

Comment: The names can be wildly different strings and they can exist on different levels of the xml doc.  Wildcards will not work in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to XML can handle documents of varying format quite easily. For example this query will get the "15" for both the documents you mentioned:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.ToString().Contains("numbers"));
```